# Policy based authentication with OKTA OpenIdConnect

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, okta, group-policy

I have a .net core app that uses OpenIdConnect as default authentication scheme using a custom Authorization server

```
services.AddAuthentication(authenticationOptions =>
        {
            authenticationOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect(openIdOptions =>
        {
            openIdOptions.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            openIdOptions.Authority = issuer;
            openIdOptions.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
            openIdOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Okta:ClientId"];
            openIdOptions.CallbackPath = OktaDefaults.CallbackPath;
            openIdOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Okta:ClientSecret"];
            openIdOptions.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Token;
            openIdOptions.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            openIdOptions.Scope.Add("openid");
            openIdOptions.Scope.Add("profile");
            openIdOptions.Scope.Add("groups");
            openIdOptions.SaveTokens = true;
        });
```

I am also using policy based authentication

```
services.AddAuthorization(authOptions =>{authOptions.AddPolicy(“QSGAdminPolicy”,policy => policy.RequireRole(Configuration.GetValue(“SecurityRoles:QSGAdminRole”)));
        authOptions.AddPolicy("QSGReadOnlyPolicy",
            policy => policy.RequireRole(Configuration.GetValue<string>("SecurityRoles:QSGReadOnlyRole")));

        authOptions.AddPolicy("QSGReviewerPolicy",
            policy => policy.RequireRole(Configuration.GetValue<string>("SecurityRoles:QSGReviewerRole"), Configuration.GetValue<string>("SecurityRoles:QSGTraderRole"), Configuration.GetValue<string>("SecurityRoles:.QSGAdminRole")));

        authOptions.AddPolicy("QSGTraderPolicy",
           policy => policy.RequireRole(Configuration.GetValue<string>("SecurityRoles:QSGTraderRole"), Configuration.GetValue<string>("SecurityRoles:QSGAdminRole")));
    });
```

in my controller I marking the API with authorize tag and the policy

```
[Route(“test/authentication”)]
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Policy = “QSGReviewerPolicy”)]
public ActionResult GetTestAuth()
{
  var claims = HttpContext.User.Claims;
  return “user allowed”;
}
```

but I am getting error:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
Connection id "0HLU51T84D7HA", Request id "0HLU51T84D7HA:00000001": An unhandled exception was 
thrown by the application.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
at System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity.HasClaim(String type, String value)
at System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.IsInRole(String role)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Infrastructure.RolesAuthorizationRequirement. 
<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<HandleRequirementAsync>b__0(String r)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Infrastructure.RolesAuthorizationRequirement.
HandleRequirementAsync(Au  
thorizationHandlerContext context, RolesAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationHandler`1.HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext 
context)
at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Infrastructure.PassThroughAuthorizationHandler.
HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(ClaimsPrincipal 
user, Object resource, IEnumerable`1 requirements)
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.PolicyEvaluator.AuthorizeAsync(AuthorizationPolicy 
  policy, AuthenticateResult authenticationResult, HttpContext context, Object resource)
   at 
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter.
OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext 
 context)
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext] 
(IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

It seems that it is not finding the values in the groups claim. if I remove the policy from the controller and use just [Authorize] it works and I receive back a token with the groups claim
how can I secure my API with policy at authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have correctly setting your roles in `appsettings.json`:

```
"SecurityRoles": {
    "QSGReviewerRole": "QSGReviewerRole",
    "QSGTraderRole": "QSGTraderRole",
    "QSGAdminRole": "QSGAdminRole"
}
```

Otherwise the error occurs because application can't read the value from config . Look into your code :

```
authOptions.AddPolicy("QSGReviewerPolicy",
        policy => policy.RequireRole(Configuration.GetValue<string>("SecurityRoles:QSGReviewerRole"), Configuration.GetValue<string>("SecurityRoles:QSGTraderRole"), Configuration.GetValue<string>("SecurityRoles:.QSGAdminRole")));
```

Notice you are using `SecurityRoles:.QSGAdminRole` . I think it should be `SecurityRoles:QSGAdminRole`